# Error message in Datasheet View

Tags: datasheet, bulk

I keep getting the two error message when trying to copy/paste or use the autofill or fill down options on a list in datasheet view.

Datasheet bulk edit option is turned on and all columns which require data to be entered are on the datasheet view.

My clients need the ability to bulk-edit list entries, for example, when a supervisor changes.  I tested the ability to edit in datasheet view on another list (my personal site) and works fine.

Here are error messages.  **Any help is GREATLY APPRECIATED.**

[image: Windows Internet Explorer (when I try to copy and paste)]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

First error message is probably because you have missed a mandatory column in the view. So when you try to add items, the mandatory field will not get any value and you will not be able to add the item

Second could be due to a mandatory field missing, or could be due to one of the missing fields with both data validation and a default value (that fails the validation).

However I think it should be due to one or more mandatory fields missing from the view. Just check and add those to your view.

Comment: Nisary, thank you very much for your response.  The resolution did have to do with mandatory fields.  I studied a bit from home this weekend and found that I had to remove the "Require this column require information" option in List Settings on the customized list itself, but also had to remove the option from the associated content type (Item).  That, my friend is the step I was missing.

Comment: That's great! So both the messages were due to a single error, right?

Comment: YES!!!!!!  Sorry for misspelling your name, Nisarg.  :)